# What is the difference between WM_QUIT, WM_CLOSE, and WM_DESTROY in a windows program?

Tags: c++, windows, message

I was wondering what the difference between the WM_QUIT, WM_CLOSE, and WM_DESTROY messages in a windows program, essentially: when are they sent, and do they have any automatic effects besides what's defined by the program?

Comment: very good quest

Answer (score 113, accepted):

They are totally different.

`WM_CLOSE` is sent to the window when it is being closed - when its "X" button is clicked, or "Close" is chosen from the window's menu, or <kbd>Alt-F4</kbd> is pressed while the window has focus, etc. If you catch this message, this is your decision how to treat it - ignore it, or really close the window. By default, `WM_CLOSE` passed to `DefWindowProc()` causes the window to be destroyed.

`WM_DESTROY` is sent to the window when it starts to be destroyed. In this stage, in opposition to `WM_CLOSE`, you cannot stop the process, you can only make any necessary cleanup. When you catch `WM_DESTROY`, none of its child windows have been destroyed yet.

`WM_NCDESTROY` is sent to the window when it is finishing being destroyed. All of its child windows have been destroyed by this time.

`WM_QUIT` is not related to any window (the `hwnd` got from `GetMessage()` is NULL, and no window procedure is called). This message indicates that the message loop should be stopped and the application should exit. When `GetMessage()` reads `WM_QUIT`, it returns 0 to indicate that. Take a look at [a typical message loop snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#creating-a-message-loop) - the loop is continued while `GetMessage()` returns non-zero.

`WM_QUIT` can be sent by the `PostQuitMessage()` function. This function is usually called when the main window receives `WM_DESTROY` (see [a typical window procedure snippet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues#posting-a-message)).

Comment: @ad88 would be great to add what happens when User Logout / `WM_ENDSESSION` arrives. Does this automatically trigger WM_CLOSE / QUIT / DESTROY ?

Comment: When a session ends, any remaining windows that still exist are simply destroyed by the OS, there are no `WM_CLOSE`/`WM_DESTROY` messages sent to them. They have their last chance to cleanup by handling `WM_(QUERY)ENDSESSION`. After all, all bets are off. See [Windows doesn't close windows when a user logs off; that's your call](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080421-00/?p=22663)

Answer (score 13):

First of all, the [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617.aspx) and [WM_DESTROY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632620.aspx) messages are associated with particular windows whereas the [WM_QUIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632641.aspx) message is applicable to the whole application (well thread) and the message is never received through a window procedure (`WndProc` routine), but only through the `GetMessage` or `PeekMessage` functions.

In your `WndProc` routine the `DefWindowProc` function takes care of the default behavoir of these messages. The [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617.aspx) messages requests that the application should close and the default behavoir for this is to call the `DestroyWindow` function. Its when this `DestroyWindow` function is called that the [WM_DESTROY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632620.aspx) message is sent. Notice that the [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617.aspx) is only a message requesting that you close (like [WM_QUIT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632641.aspx)) - you don't actually have to exit/quit. But the [WM_DESTROY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632620.aspx) message tells you that your window **IS** being closed and destroyed so you must cleanup any resources, handles etc.

Comment: Not to the whole application, but to a particular message loop. Each thread may have its own message loop, so an application can have several message loops.

Answer (score 6):

Just so it doesn't get lost in the comments... don't forget about `WM_CANCEL`. When you click the close (x) button on an MFC dialog, it will certainly send `WM_CLOSE`. The default `OnClose()` function will then call the default (base class) `OnCancel()` function.

However, if you simply type the `ESC` key, this will lead to the closure of the dialog, but (as far as I can tell) without generating the `WM_CLOSE` event - it goes directly to the `WM_CANCEL/OnCancel()` mechanism.

I hereby invite the community to elaborate on this... or edit that elaboration into the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but just trying to provide a clearer answer for anyone.

```
// What causes each message?
WM_CLOSE:       // Pressed Close Button (X) / Alt+F4 / "Close" in context menu
WM_DESTROY:     // Called DestroyWindow(hwnd)
WM_QUIT:        // Called PostQuitMessage(exit)
```

---

```
// What do they do by default?
case WM_CLOSE: DestroyWindow(hwnd); return 0; // pressed close? destroy window.
case WM_DESTROY: PostQuitMessage(0); return 0; // destroyed window? quit message loop.
// WM_QUIT isn't associated with a window, so isn't sent to the window procedure
```

---

So `WM_CLOSE` is just so we can request to destroy the window. However you might want it to show a popup in your game asking if you're sure. (and if you want to save first)

And `WM_DESTROY` doesn't actually post the quit message by default, since you could have multiple windows. That's just the usual event we quit after. You could have `WM_CLOSE` call `PostQuitMessage(exit)` and destroy your window(s) after the message loop if you wanted.

If you wanted a custom close button in your game, it should do what `WM_CLOSE` does.

Also there is the function `CloseWindow(hwnd)`, however it simply minimizes the window.

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 2):

At first let's discuss WM_QUIT - the difference from another messages that  this is not associated with window. It is used by application. For example this can be handled by non-visible standalone OLE server (.exe, but not in-proc as .dll)

WM_CLOSE - per msdn: "*An application can prompt the user for confirmation, prior to destroying a window*" - it is used as notification about intention to close (you can reject this intention).

WM_DESTROY - is a fact that window is closing and all resources must(!) be deallocated.

Comment: @atzz yes, you are right. Talking in general this message notifies event loop to stop handling at all, regardless application-wide or standalone thread.