# Win32 Message Loops: Quitting after window closes with GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)?

Tags: c, winapi, window, message-loop

If I have the following code below, how do I detect when the window has been closed, so I can quit? `r` never seems to get the value <strike>`-1`</strike> `0`, and I need to process messages for the entire thread, not just the current window.

```
HWND hWnd = CreateWindowExW(0, L"Edit", L"My Window", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 200, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);
MSG msg;
BOOL r;
while ((r = GetMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) != 0)
{
    if (r == -1) { break; }
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessageW(&msg);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Waiting for `r = -1` is not the way you detect that your window has closed. A return value of -1 is not a normal condition: it indicates that an error has occurred in the message loop.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936.aspx):

> **Return Value**
>
> Type: **`BOOL`**
>
> If the function retrieves a message other than `WM_QUIT`, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function retrieves the `WM_QUIT` message, the return value is zero.
>
> If there is an error, the return value is -1. For example, the function fails if hWnd is an invalid window handle or `lpMsg` is an invalid pointer. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

When `GetMessage` retrieves a `WM_QUIT` message from the queue, it will return a value of 0, and you should end the loop.

If you just want to know when the window has closed, you probably want to handle either the [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617.aspx) or [`WM_DESTROY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632620.aspx) messages. For a discussion of these messages, see the answers to this question: [What is the difference between WM_QUIT, WM_CLOSE, and WM_DESTROY in a windows program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155782/what-is-the-difference-between-wm-quit-wm-close-and-wm-destroy-in-a-windows-pro)

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot `r == -1` isn't the close condition. But isn't it also supposed to exit with `r == 0`? How come it's not doing that? (By the way, I `WM_QUIT` is never sent to the loop.)

Comment: @Mehrdad: Yes, my answer addressed that `WM_QUIT` is never sent to the message loop. If `GetMessage` retrieves `WM_QUIT`, it returns a value of 0. Presumably, the issue is that you never *send* a `WM_QUIT` message. You need to handle the case when the window is closed, and use the [`PostQuitMessage` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644945.aspx) to indicate the loop should exit.

Comment: Ohh wait... so if I need to send it, and I have multiple windows open with many controls inside each other, how do I know whether I'm the last window open, and so whether I should send it from WndProc? Doesn't keeping track of it become pretty ugly?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Most applications have a "main" window, that exits the program when closed regardless of what other windows are open.  If you do have peer windows, just keep count in a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this: [`WM_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
The message loop can handle the matter on its own independently of `WndProc`:

```
// written in C# 
MSG msg = new MSG();
while (GetMessage(out msg, window, 0, 0))
{
    if ((msg.message == WM_NULL) && !IsWindow(window))
        break;
    TranslateMessage(ref msg);
    DispatchMessage(ref msg);
}
Console.WriteLine("yeah, out of loop ^^");
```

**From my observation:** When window is destroyed `GetMessage` retrieves `WM_NULL` messages without pause (1st hint) and [`IsWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633528%28VS.85%29.aspx) can check the window (affirmation).