# Why is there a difference in the order WM_DESTROY is received between child and owned windows?

Tags: c, winapi

With child windows the parent first receives `WM_DESTROY` then the child windows. With owned windows it's the opposite. The owned windows first receive `WM_DESTROY` then the owner. If I want to modify something that will affect the child windows, I can do it in `WM_DESTROY` of parent window, but I can't do the same with owned windows. Owned windows will receive `WM_DESTROY` before the owner does.

Comment: [What is the difference between WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050726-00/?p=34803)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [official documentation for `DestroyWindow()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682(v=vs.85).aspx) says otherwise:

> If the specified window is a parent or owner window, `DestroyWindow` automatically destroys the associated child or owned windows when it destroys the parent or owner window. The function first destroys child or owned windows, and then it destroys the parent or owner window.

Are you sending `WM_DESTROY` by hand instead of calling `DestroyWindow()`?

Comment: I'm not sending `WM_DESTROY`. I wrote a test program and for child windows it's the opposite of what the documentation says. Child windows receive `WM_DESTROY` after parent does

Comment: @Rm32a: Ahh, [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3155879/103167) contains the key: `WM_NCDESTROY` is sent in actual order of destruction, `WM_DESTROY` is sent early, before the check for and destruction of child windows.

Comment: The answer given seems to be the right answer to your question. If you send WM_DESTROY to a window (either via SendMessage, PostMessage or DestroyWindow), the OS will thereafter send WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY to its children, How else would the OS know that child windows need get this message if it wasn't first sent to the parent? Perhaps I misunderstand your question.

Comment: @clarasoft-it: No, **you** don't send `WM_DESTROY` to a window.  `DestroyWindow` sends `WM_DESTROY` and `WM_NCDESTROY` and actually performs the destruction.  See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110926-00

Comment: Interesting link, thank you. I will explore this deeper.